# Validate a filename in python

Tags: python, filenames

I'm writing a personal wiki-style program in Python that stores text files in a user configurable directory.

The program should be able to take a string (e.g. `foo`) from a user and create a filename of `foo.txt`. The user will only be able to create the file inside the wiki directory, and slashes will create a subdir (e.g. `foo/bar` becomes `(path-to-wiki)/foo/bar.txt`).

What is the best way to check that the input is as safe as possible? What do I need to watch out for? I know some common pitfalls are:

- Directory traversal: `../`
- Null bytes: `\0`

I realize that taking user input for filenames is never 100% safe, but the program will only be run locally and I just want to guard for any common errors/glitches.

Comment: What target operating system?  What versions of python?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: yes, but plain text files in the file-system have other benefits.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: Python 2.7 and/or 3.2, and MacOS/Linux primarily.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can enforce the user to create a file/directory inside wiki by normalizing the path with [os.path.normpath](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) and then checking if the path begins with say '(path-to-wiki)'

```
os.path.normpath('(path-to-wiki)/foo/bar.txt').startswith('(path-to-wiki)')
```

To ensure that the user's entered path/filename doesn't contain anything nasty, you can force the user to enter a path or filename to either of Lower/Upper Alpha, Numeric Digits or may be hyphen or underscore.

Then you can always check the normalized filename using a similar regular expression

```
userpath=os.path.normpath('(path-to-wiki)/foo/bar.txt')
re.findall(r'[^A-Za-z0-9_\-\\]',userpath)
```

To summarize

if `userpath=os.path.normpath('(path-to-wiki)/foo/bar.txt')` then

```
if not os.path.normpath('(path-to-wiki)/foo/bar.txt').startswith('(path-to-wiki)')  
   or re.search(r'[^A-Za-z0-9_\-\\]',userpath):
  ... Do what ever you want with an invalid path
```

Comment: Your regex is is a little extreme! There are so many more characters that are allowed in paths!

Comment: Also, to don't allow forward slashes in your paths?

Answer (score 7):

now there is a full library to **validate strings**:
[check it out:](https://pypi.org/project/pathvalidate/)

```
from pathvalidate import sanitize_filepath

fpath = "fi:l*e/p\"a?t>h|.t<xt"
print("{} -> {}".format(fpath, sanitize_filepath(fpath)))

fpath = "\0_a*b:c<d>e%f/(g)h+i_0.txt"
print("{} -> {}".format(fpath, sanitize_filepath(fpath)))
```

output:

```
fi:l*e/p"a?t>h|.t<xt -> file/path.txt
_a*b:c<d>e%f/(g)h+i_0.txt -> _abcde%f/(g)h+i_0.txt
```

Comment: You probably want to use `sanitize_filename` to avoid keeping slashes in the string (which stand for subdirectories)

Answer (score 6):

Armin Ronacher [has a blog post on this subject](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2010/12/24/common-mistakes-as-web-developer/) (and others).

These ideas are implemented as the [safe_join()](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/50dc2403526c5c5c67577767b05eb81e8fab0877/flask/helpers.py#L605) function in Flask:

```py
def safe_join(directory, filename):
    """Safely join `directory` and `filename`.
    Example usage::
        @app.route('/wiki/<path:filename>')
        def wiki_page(filename):
            filename = safe_join(app.config['WIKI_FOLDER'], filename)
            with open(filename, 'rb') as fd:
                content = fd.read() # Read and process the file content...
    :param directory: the base directory.
    :param filename: the untrusted filename relative to that directory.
    :raises: :class:`~werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound` if the resulting path
             would fall out of `directory`.
    """
    filename = posixpath.normpath(filename)
    for sep in _os_alt_seps:
        if sep in filename:
            raise NotFound()
    if os.path.isabs(filename) or filename.startswith('../'):
        raise NotFound()
    return os.path.join(directory, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just validate all the characters are printable alphanumeric ascii except for the ' ','.', and '/' characters then just remove all instances of bad combinations...

```
safe_string = str()
for c in user_supplied_string:
    if c.isalnum() or c in [' ','.','/']:
        safe_string = safe_string + c

while safe_string.count("../"):
    # I use a loop because only replacing once would 
    # leave a hole in that a bad guy could enter ".../"
    # which would be replaced to "../" so the loop 
    # prevents tricks like this!
    safe_string = safe_string.replace("../","./")
# Get rid of leading "./" combinations...
safe_string = safe_string.lstrip("./")
```

That's what I would do, I don't know how pythonic it is but it should leave you pretty safe. If you wanted to validate and not convert then you could just do a test for equality after that like so:

```
valid = save_string == user_supplied_string
if not valid:
     raise Exception("Sorry the string %s contains invalid characters" % user_supplied_string )
```

In the end both approaches would probably work, I find this method feels a bit more explicit and should also screen out any weird/non-appropriate characters like '\t','\r', or '\n' 
Cheers!

Comment: You can have non-ASCII filenames.