# Check if string could be a filename

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to check if an input string given by a user could be a valid file name for an output file, lets say a gif.

The user may provide different kinds of input, e.g., they may provide a full path like `a/b/c.gif` or just a directory `a/b` or `a/b/`. I can check these using `os.path.isdir(user_path)` and `os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(user_path))`.

How should I check if I just receive a file name without a directory? I could do something like `not os.path.dirname(user_path) and user_path.endswith('.gif')` but that would allow still allow a lot of unwanted characters etc.

I am sure there is a neater way to check this. Looking forward to your solution =)

EDIT: at the time I am trying to check the user input, I do not have access to the full path, I will later write to - have to determine the parent directory first. So a solution without touching the file or similar would be preferred.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34102855/20121320) answer your question?

Comment: I think you might find your answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686880/validate-a-filename-in-python
at least it solved my problem in the past !

Comment: @FlorentMonin the answer you are referring to helps me to solve it. I do not really have access to the full path at the time I want to validate the input. But I can create a dummy path just from the filename. Still cannot believe that there is no library for that though..