# What character guaranteed NOT to be in filename (Unix/Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filenames

Approaching [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename) from a different angle, what character `#` could I use in my input file below:

```
1#2#3#/home/user/foo.txt
4#5#6#/home/user/foo.test.---.txt
7#8#9#/home/user/foo. .   .!!+.txt
...
```

Such that when I tokenize it (in C++ using `strtok (str, "#")` ) I am guaranteed that the file name will not break my program?

Comment: Doesn't matter, just pick a delimiter, and escape any existing delimiter characters already in the string. This is how strings can contain quotation marks.

Comment: @meagar yes, but this is a program users are going to use, it would be a burden if they went around and escaped potentially hundreds of delimeters (especially if they are not programmers and do it in, for example, notepad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only two characters. The null byte `'\0'` and the slash `'/'`.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename):

> In Unix-like file systems the null character, as that is the end-of-string indicator and the path separator / are prohibited.

But instead do what @meagar said, and escape whatever character you're using.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for. I'll just go with the comma...not too many files with the comma in them.

Comment: Do what @meagar said and escape whatever character you're using.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the only guarantee is null or '/' but if you want to use something else, a less commonly used character in file names than comma, which is actually fairly common, would be the newline character.

Comment: I actually thought about that, except that rows are separated by newlines. I could in theory use modular arithmetic, but it is just not intuitive to have it that way. I'll just put a note at the top not to use commas in file names