# fopen filename running environment

Tags: c++, linux, windows

Using C++ on Windows XP, Windows 7 and Linux.

Reading the fopen documentation (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) about filename:

> C string containing the name of the file to be opened. Its value shall follow the file name      specifications of the running environment and can include a path (if supported by the system).

What does "running environment" mean in this context? The operating system or file systems?

How do I determine what is supported filename for various platforms (without doing trial and error) ?

Comment: Near duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4814040/179910. As to the "what does it mean part", it mostly means: "Reading cplusplus.com was a mistake. You should have gone to cppreference.com instead."

Comment: You determine what is a supported filename for a platform by reading the documentation for that platform.

Answer (score 1):

That means that in Windows you need to specify the path using forward slashes while in Linux/Unix backwards slashes(despite of filesystem type).

**Windows example filename:** C:/some_path/filename

**Unix/Linux/Mac example filename:** \some_path\filename

Also means that you can't violate the name spacifications for file names, for instance Windows(NTFS, FAT, ...) don't allow the use of `?` caracter while Linux does.

Hence, you can say that "running environment" here refers to both, operating system and file system.

Comment: You've got the slashes in your examples reversed.

Comment: @Lars Dude, you didn't update your question, yo make an enterely new. That last question has nothing to do with the original.

Comment: Raydel: Sorry, I have seen other people update their original question, just thought that was the norm. Will move update section to another post.

Comment: @Lars, It is not personal. People update question when the question isn't very clear or people needs more info about the current problem. But is not fear that someone help us, answer our initial question, and then (even without mark the question as solved) we ask another question.