# Problematic characters for filename in chrome.downloads.download

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Using certain characters in the filename argument to the function [chrome.downloads.download](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download) leads to an "Invalid filename" error, when starting the download. I can't find any information in the documentation and replacing for example : with %3A or &#58 ; doesn't work.

The problematic characters are:

```
: " ? ~ < > * |
```

Here is an example you can use in the background page console from any extension with the downloads permission.

```
chrome.downloads.download(
    {url: "http://i.imgur.com/3cWNMt3.webm",
     filename: "title:subtitle.webm"},
    function (downloadId) {
        if (downloadId===undefined)
            console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        else
            console.log("Ok");
});
```

Is there a way to use these problematic characters?

*Edit:* Is there a list for the characters chrome.downloads.download doesn't support?

*Edit 2:* To put it another way. The user can manually download a file in Chrome (Linux) and, in the download dialog, name it:

```
title:subtitle.extension
```

I would like to do the same in my extension.

This filename is just an example, the filenames get generated automatically depending on the webpage and some user generated rules.

Comment: Why would you want to use those characters in download file names? They are problematic in most file systems too. (Not all of them in all file systems – but since you don’t know what OS/file systems the users of your extension(?) will be using …)

Comment: I would anticipate this would be the same as the typical ones.  Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename.  There really isn't a way to use these, filenames are basically native so you can't just encode them like a url, because there's no place to decode them on the other end.

Comment: The filenames get automatically generated. I would rather give the user the choice what to do, than strip the problematic characters.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu and if I download a file with chrome I can name it ": " ? ~ < > * |.png" and it downloads just fine.

Comment: Your edited question makes little sense. The API itself will happily consime almost everything (there's a small list of exceptions in the docs like `..`), but then the underlying filesystem/OS can refuse some names. Chrome does not know about it in advance.

Comment: On Linux the opposite is the case. The API doesn't happily consume the filename. The error doesn't come from the filesystem, because all the characters are permitted.

Comment: Interesting information. Still, if you're looking for a cross-platform safe list of characters, see the link at the end of my question.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to use these problematic characters?

No. That would be an *invalid filename*.

**What exactly is invalid varies by OS.** Here's a [full ruleset for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247).

A common strategy is to replace the characters with something allowed; for example, `_`

See also [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/358855/what-characters-are-safe-in-cross-platform-file-names-for-linux-windows-and-os).