# Sensible way to create filenames for files based on URLs?

Tags: python, filesystems, naming

I am screenshotting a bunch of web pages, using Python with Selenium. I want to save the  PNGs locally for reference. The list of URLs looks something like this:

```
www.mysite.com/dir1/pageA
www.mysite.com/dir1/pageB
```

My question is about what filenames to give the screenshotted PNGs.

If I call the image files e.g. `www.mysite.com/dir1/pageA.png` the meaningless slashes will inevitably cause problems at some point.

I could replace all the `/` characters in the URL with `_`, but I suspect that might cause problems too, e.g. if there are already `_` characters in the URL. (I don't strictly need to be able to work backwards from the filename to the URL, but it wouldn't be a bad thing.)

What's a sensible way to handle the naming?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to represent what's almost certainly a directory structure on the server is to do like `wget` does and replicate that structure on your local machine.

Thus the `/` characters become directory delimiters, and your `www.mysite.com/dir1/pageA.png` would become a PNG file called `pageA.png` in a directory called `dir1`, and `dir1` is located in a directory called `www.mysite.com`.

It's simple, guaranteed to be reversible, and doesn't risk ambiguous results.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use '%2F'? It's the '/' but html encoded.

source:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: In general, `%` is a problematic character for use in a file name.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename for a full discussion.