# Image name have slash like "/" getting error php

Tags: php, image

I have image with the name abc.jpg when I convert this image in PNG format and change the Image name like "Burks_10DF4-1-1/4-AB-MV.png" it consider slash to directory that I am giving in the image name and getting error. anybody please guide how to resolve this issue.

> I am getting this error "Message:
>   imagepng(Burks_10DF4-1-1/4-AB-MV.png): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory"

Thanks

Comment: "/" is not a valid character for any filename. there is no fix except to use a valid file name.............

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed characters in filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename)

Comment: Image name that I am adding is coming from DataBase that is Model name. so I want to change the default image name with Model name. is there any way to do this?

Comment: not if the model name contains a "/". the end user will never see the filename anyway so why is it important?

Comment: my client have requirement change  image name with Model name. so there are lot of Model name that have "/".

Comment: well... you could actually turn them into directories so the file **path** looks like that, but youre wasting you time tryig to figure out how to make the file **name** look like that because it will never happen. we all get retarded clients sometimes. it happens.

Comment: yes , I replace the slash with some specific char. Thanks