# Creating a file for each character in the ASCII table

Tags: linux, bash, file, ascii

I want to make a program which will create files named as characters from the ASCII table. So 128 files from 1 to 127

I did something like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash

temp=0;

for (( x=0; $x <= 177; x++ )) ; do
    temp=$((temp+1))
    if [ "$temp" = 8 ]; then
    temp=$((0))
    x=$((x+3))
    fi

    echo "$x"

    `touch $'\"$x"'`
done
```

I know that it's written very weirdly, but what this program does is:
counting from 0 to 127 in oct (so from 0 to 177oct). The problem is that `touch $'\"$x"'` doesn't work properly.

Although `touch $'\101'` will make a file named "A".

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Note that you can't create a file whose name contains the null byte. You'll have to start with `x=1`.

Comment: Putting the `touch` command in backticks doesn't do anything, by the way: it'll try to execute its output as a command, but there isn't any.

Comment: Related, [Which common charecters are illegal in Unix AND WIndows filesystems?](https://serverfault.com/q/242110/145545), [Allowed characters in filename](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4814040/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
for num in {0..127}; do
    printf -v fname "\x$(printf '%x' "$num")"
    touch "$fname"
done
```

Notice that the null character and `/` are not allowed in a file name.

Here is what this does:

the outer

```
printf -v fname '\xHH'
```

stores the byte with the hex value *`HH`* (one or two digits) in the variable `fname`. This gets around the problem where for the value 10 (ASCII newline), command substitution would strip the newline (as it did in the previous revision of this answer), leaving just the empty string.

The inner

```
printf '%x' "$num"
```

prints the value of `num` as a hexadecimal number, which is then used as the *`HH`* value of the outer `printf`.

Say, for example, the value of `num` is decimal 80. The inner substitution does this:

```
$ printf '%x' 80
50
```

So the value of the inner command substitution is 50 (hexadecimal for 80). Now the command becomes

```
printf -v fname "\x50"
```

and because of

```
$ printf "\x50"
P
```

the next command becomes

```
touch P
```

which is what we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` doesn't provide any particularly simple way to produce a character given an ASCII code point. `printf` supports converting a decimal value to a hexadecimal representation:

```
$ printf '%x\n' 65
A
```

but you need a `bash` extension to convert a decimal string to a hexadecimal string to use to construct the standard format:

```
# null characters not allows, start with x=1, not x=0
for ((x=1; x <= 177; x++)); do
    h=$(printf '%x' "$x")  # e.g. 65 -> 41
    c=$(printf "\\x$h")    # e.g. 41 -> A
    [[ $c = "/" ]] && continue  # / is not a valid character for file names
    touch "$c"
done
```

Note that backquotes are only needed capture the output of the command to use in a larger expression.