# Issue with .NET Core Named Pipes on Linux (address already in use)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am looking into using named pipes to control some aspects of a .net core application running under linux (ex: triggering a save, shutdown, etc).

I am trying to create a `NamedPipeServerStream` inside the application, however it always fails with the following message: `Address already in use` (I tried different names, nothing helps).

I have also attempted creating a temporary pipe using `/tmp/somepipename`, however this also fails with the following message: `The name of a pipe on this platform must only include characters valid in file names.`

From looking at the .NET Core tests for named pipes, this shouldn't be an issue as they also use `Path.GetTemporaryFileName()` to generate a temporary pipe

Here is the usage: [NamedPipeTestBase.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/bffef76f6af208e2042a2f27bc081ee908bb390b/src/System.IO.Pipes/tests/NamedPipeTests/NamedPipeTestBase.cs#L50)

And here is the implementation of `GetUniquePipeName`: [PipeTestBase.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/8d51233795da222041c23d33b1eb44bbe458d0eb/src/System.IO.Pipes/tests/PipeTestBase.cs#L81)

Just in case, here is the code I am using (one liner, pretty simple):

```
_pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("somepipename", PipeDirection.InOut,1);
```

Am I doing something wrong, or are Named Pipes not fully implemented for Linux yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding the error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The name of
>   a pipe on this platform must only include characters valid in file
>   names.

[This is the expected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename). Your input (`/tmp/somepipename`) is a fully qualified path and not a file name. An example of a valid file name would be: `some.pipe`

The forward slash is valid when using named pipes on some platforms though. That's why you can see the [CoreFX test class](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/8d51233795da222041c23d33b1eb44bbe458d0eb/src/System.IO.Pipes/tests/PipeTestBase.cs#L81) has the check on `IsInAppContainer` before prepending the slash. [IsInAppContainer](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/475bfdd5b0b2bcc21b5fd96f4dabf07b9ac418c8/src/CoreFx.Private.TestUtilities/src/System/PlatformDetection.Windows.cs#L132)'s code shows that if it's not Windows, it would always return `false` and not add the slash.

I've tested the client server connection via named pipes on a MacOS 10.12.6 and CentOS 7.2 and it worked as expected. You can actually see some [Unix specific implementation of PipeStream on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.Pipes/src/System/IO/Pipes/PipeStream.Unix.cs).

I believe the error raised:

> Address already in use

Comes from your program trying to bind to a IP/port combination already in use. Could that be the case?
If not, please provide your solution so I can troubleshoot it on a Linux machine.