# How can I add a list of file paths in a string in an XML attribute?

Tags: xml

I am trying to place a list of attachments in an xml attribute but can't find the best delimiter for the string. I am trying to conserve the reserved characters and either they don't look great or I am not sure if they are good to use.

Basically I am trying to find a good delimiter that doesn't conflict with anything else.

Best is 'pipe' at the moment.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename

Comment: Jordan, do you have the luxury of being able to store serialized JSON as the attribute?

Comment: I don't know or use JSON. All I want is a good delimiter.

Comment: I don't think that is how you use a commment here.