# access macro empty file output

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hi I have the following code, which when run, should create an output excel file with data, retrieved using an query within the macro. However when the output file is created it's a empty file which when clicked on will not open and displays an error message.  When the query itself is run via design view it works fine so I don't think its the query part causing the issue. I've also used the coding (which is attached to a button on a dashboard) on other buttons and it works fine. Any Ideas what would cause this?

```
Dim xls As Excel.Application
Dim wkb As Excel.workbook
Dim wks As Excel.worksheet
Dim strFilePath As String

On Error Resume Next
strFilePath = "C:\xxx\xxx\Monthly MI : Submission Data -    Electronic Submissions.xlsx"
Kill strFilePath

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "qryMonthlyMISubmissionDataElectronicSubmissions", "C:\xxx\xxx\" & "Monthly MI : Submission Data - Electronic Submissions.xlsx", True
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Set xls = New Excel.Application
xls.Visible = True
Set wkb = xls.Workbooks.Open("C:\xxx\xxx\Monthly MI : Submission Data - Electronic Submissions.xlsx", , True)
wkb.Activate
wkb.ActiveSheet.Columns("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Set xls = Nothing
Set wkb = Nothing
```

Comment: Which error message? What have you tried?  It would be helpful if you reduce your code to include only the part that is the problem. For example, create a file but only use a example piece of data to see if you still get the problem.  See **how to create a [mcve]** as well as [this **checklist**](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use colons (`:`) in filenames since they are used to specify a drive letter (like `c:`).

---

### More Information:

- Microsoft Docs : [**Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces**](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file)
- Wikipedia : [**FileName**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename)
- Stack Overflow : [**Allowed characters in filenames**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35352640/8112776)