# Can open() deal with a filepath ending in '\r'?

Tags: python, filenames, carriage-return

I'm on a mac, and I have a collection of files where some file names end in `\r` carriage-return (don't ask why).

I can rename those files and drop the trailing `\r`, but I don't want to - the files are in a Font package and on principle I don't want to mess with it.

I've tried these things; all failed.

```
f = open("Icon\r")    file not found
f = open(r"Icon\r")   file not found
f = open(U"Icon\r")   file not found
f = open("Icon")      as expected, file not found
```

Is there any way to make Python accept `\r` within a filename?

Comment: Are you sure it's a `\r`? How does python see it? ([`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to check.)

Comment: You could try coding a C program....

Comment: @Ouroborus: `os.walk` is going to show a lot more than needed, a mere `print(os.listdir())` would show all the entries in the working directory (the place an unqualified `open` call will be looking). I don't think Python imposes any restrictions on filenames beyond those of the OS, so if the OS allows file names to contain carriage returns, Python can use/create such files. `print(os.getcwd())` will tell you if you're in the working directory you expect to be in.

Comment: If those don't work, then the file name contains something else than you claim.

Comment: Is it possible that you're in the wrong directory when you call `open()`? When I test this on my system, I can open the file just fine.

Comment: The OP also posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72805695/please-re-open-my-question-about-carriage-return-in-filenames-on-mac which basically confirms this as a duplicate of [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem for Python with a filename having a trailing `'\r'` character, the only prohibited character is the path separator `'/'`.

If `open("Icon\r")` gives a file not found error, then the filename is not really `"Icon\r"`.

Use [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to see what the filenames *really* are.

Comment: I am sure that this file name ends with carriage-return, ordinal value 13:

>>> ld = os.listdir("./Pattern Pack 1")

>>> pprint(ld)

['Icon\r',

 'PP1_readme',

 'Pattern Pack #1 3D',

 'Pattern Pack #1 Filled',

 'Pattern Pack #1 Inverse',

 'Pattern Pack #1 Outline']

>>> "\r" in ld[0]

True

>>> ord(ld[0][-1])

13
>>>

Answer (score 0):

If your file- and operating-system does support, Python should be fine too:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path 

print(os.name) 
# 'posix'

print(Path('test\r'))
# PosixPath('test\r')
print(Path('test\r').exists())
# False

# Now, let's create an example folder containing a carriage-return (CR) in name
os.mkdir('test\r')
print(Path('test\r').exists())
# True
```

Afterwards in the console the directory can be found:

```bash
ls test*
'test'$'\r'
```

#### See also

- [Allowed characters in filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename)
- [regular expression - How can I find and remove files with a carriage return (\r) in the filename? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612508/how-can-i-find-and-remove-files-with-a-carriage-return-r-in-the-filename)
- [rename - How do I remove carriage returns from directory names? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60779/how-do-i-remove-carriage-returns-from-directory-names)