# Permission denied for mv command in Git Bash for Windows

Tags: git-bash, mv

I have created two directories in desktop: `solid/` and `liquid/`. Initially `liquid/` is empty.
Directory structure:

```
├── liquid
├── solid
│   ├── rock.txt
│   └── water.txt
```

I tried to move `water.txt` to `liquid/` but it throws and error.

```bash
$ mv water.txt /liquid

mv: cannot move 'water.txt' to '/liquid': Permission denied
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your steps, your `Desktop/` folder should look like this:

```
├── liquid
├── solid
│   ├── rock.txt
│   └── water.txt
```

There are two major issues causing this behaviour.

1. Assuming you are currently in `solid/` directory, you need to reference the relative path of the `liquid/` directory. Since it resides in the same level as the parent directory of water.txt file, you need to use `..` (double dots) according to the unix convention. ( for more context read [dot definition](http://www.linfo.org/dot.html))

   ```bash
   # currently in solid directory
   $ pwd    
   /c/Users/USER/Desktop/solid

   # move file to liquid directory ✔
   $ mv water.txt ../liquid/
   ```
2. In Unix based systems, directories are typically represented by it's name followed by a front slash `/`, not the other way around. Ex: `music/`. In fact, putting `/` in front of a directory name is [prohibited in both Windows and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35352640/8568965).
   Moreover, when the two arguments are in the same directory, **mv** command interprets it as a **rename operation** on the first argument.

   ```bash
   # git bash thinks /liquid is a file in current directory; rename operation fails ❌
   $ mv water.txt /liquid

   # git bash thinks liquid to be in upper level; no renaming; move succeeds ✔
   $ mv water.txt ../liquid/
   ```