# Trying to create a dynamic csv file based on UTC time

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream, ctime

I am trying to create a file from C++ code with `format(name + UTC Date Time)` using `std::fstream`, but every time it is showing that it cannot create a file that I am printing using `std::cout`. No idea why this is happening.

Below is the code which is printing the output:

```
void IOfile::writeCsv(string write_file) {
    write_file.erase(std::remove_if(write_file.begin(), write_file.end(), ::isspace), write_file.end());
    cout << write_file.size() << endl;
    cout << write_file << endl;
    string placeholder = ".csv";
    string finalFile = write_file + placeholder;
    
    cout << finalFile.size()<<endl;
    cout << finalFile<< endl;

    fstream file;
    file.open(finalFile, fstream::out);
    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Error in creating file!!!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "File created successfully.";
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Place where the `writeCSV()` function is getting called. Data in below code is object of the class which contains the `writeCSV` function:

```
string dateTime = data.getDateTime();
string fileName = "Big" + dateTime;
```

Above code is calling one function `getDateTime()` which is returning the current GMT time.

```
string IOfile::getDateTime()
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    char* currentTime = ctime(&now);

    tm* gmtm = gmtime(&now);//to get GMT time
    currentTime = asctime(gmtm);

    return currentTime;
};
```

Output which I am getting:

```
23
BigMonApr2422:45:572023
27
BigMonApr2422:45:572023.csv
Error in creating file!!!
```

Comment: You coding C++ like C. Using Chrono can make your work easier.

Answer (score 2):

On many systems, you can't use `:` in a file name.  For example, on Windows:

[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)

> The following fundamental rules enable applications to create and process valid names for files and directories, regardless of the file system:
>
> - ...
> - Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), **except for the following**:
>
>   - The following reserved characters:
>
>     - `<` (less than)
>     - `>` (greater than)
>     - **`:` (colon)**
>     - `"` (double quote)
>     - `/` (forward slash)
>     - `\` (backslash)
>     - `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
>     - `?` (question mark)
>     - `*` (asterisk)
> - ...

Also see this question: [Allowed characters in filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/)

So, you need to change the `:` characters to something more acceptable, like `-` or `_`, or just eliminate them completely.

Also, consider using functions that give you control over the formatting of your file name, so that you can *include* only what you actually want rather than *removing* what you don't want.

For example, using [`std::strftime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime):

```
#include <ctime>

string IOfile::makeCsvFileName()
{
    time_t now = time(nullptr);

    char buffer[32] = {};
    strftime(buffer, size(buffer), "Big%a%b%d%H_%M_%S%Y.csv", gmtime(&now));

    return buffer;
}

void IOfile::writeCsv(string write_file) {

    cout << write_file.size() << endl;
    cout << write_file << endl;

    string placeholder = ".csv";
    string finalFile = write_file + placeholder;
    
    cout << finalFile.size() <<endl;
    cout << finalFile << endl;

    ofstream file(finalFile);
    if (!file) {
        cout << "Error in creating file!!!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "File created successfully.";
        file.close();
    }
}

...

string fileName = makeCsvFileName();
writeCsv(fileName);
```

Or, using [`std:::put_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

string IOfile::makeCsvFileName()
{
    time_t now = time(nullptr);

    ostringstream oss;
    oss << put_time(gmtime(&now), "Big%a%b%d%H_%M_%S%Y.csv");

    return oss.str();
}
```

Or, using [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format):

```
#include <format>
#include <chrono>

string IOfile::makeCsvFileName()
{
    return std::format(
        "Big{0:%a}{0:%b}{0:%d}{0:%H}_{0:%M}_{0:%S}{0:%Y}.csv",
        std::chrono::utc_clock::now()
    );
}
```

---

Just on a side note: a file name like `BigMonApr2422:45:572023.csv` is a little hard to read/understand, especially the `2422` and `572023` portions.  Consider using more readable file names, for example: `Big_YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS.csv` like `Big_2023-04-24_22-45-57.csv`