# How to match any filename with extension in a list of filenames using regex?

Tags: regex

Consider a list of filenames in a single string that looks like (every file has an extension)

`file1.tex          dhdgs kdkd.csv f-i.le.jpg`

I need to match the 3 files names such as:

`file1.tex`
`dhdgs kdkd.csv`
`f-i.le.jpg`

The following regex almost works, but :

- it includes trailing spaces in the matches :
- it doesn't work as expected when there is a `.` or a `-` into the filename

```
\b\s*([\w\s]+)\.\w+\s*\b
```

it matches: `file1.tex`           `dhdgs kdkd.csv`  `i.le`

What do I need to change to this regex pattern?

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/r4zd0C/3

Comment: `\w[\w\s]*\.\w+`? https://regex101.com/r/tfjiNu/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it almost works, but I've added a constraint when there is a dot in the filename that does not denotes the extension

Comment: Questions cast in terms of examples are rarely unambiguous and this one is no exception. For example, how do we know that the first two filenames are not `"file1.te"` and `"x          dhdgs kdkd.csv"`? You need to state your question precisely, in words. Examples are meant for illustration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use

```
\w+(?:[\s-]+\w+)*(?:\.\w+)+
```

The pattern matches:

- `\w+` Match 1+ word char
- `(?:[\s-]+\w+)*` Optional repetitions of 1+ whitespace chars or hyphens and 1+ word chars
- `(?:\.\w+)+` One or more repetitions of `.` and 1+ word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4TlAH9/1)

Or a bit broader match with whitespace boundaries (note that [the lookbehind](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) has limited support)

```
(?<!\S)[^\s.]+(?:[^\S\r\n]+[^\s.]+)*(?:\.[^\s.]+)+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yPb4hI/1)

Comment: Thanks, almost works : if the `-` character is contained into the filename, it doesn't match the whole filename. Edited the question to reflect this issue

Comment: @Victor I see, I have updated the pattern. Can there also be other allowed character besides word characters and `-` ?

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814040/allowed-characters-in-filename, it's not that simple, so I would say that any printable character should work, only the last `.` and the followings characters (the extension) should be used to delimit the filename

Comment: @Victor Did you try the last pattern? What is the tool or language that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace chars, so they appear in your matches.

You can use

```
\w[\w\s\-]*\.\w+
(?<!\S)\w.*?\.\w+(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/tfjiNu/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/tfjiNu/3).

*Details*:

- `\w`- a word char
- `[\w\s\-]*` - zero or more word or whitespace or hyphen chars
- `\.` - a dot
- `\w+` - one or more word chars.

And

- `(?<!\S)` - left-hand whitespace boundary
- `\w` - a word char
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\.` - a dot
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?!\S)` - right-hand whitespace boundary

Comment: Thanks, works fine for the original question, but I've edited it to add an edge case that is not handled with this answer.

Comment: @Victor Just add the hyphen. Or use a simple `(?<!\S)\w.*?\.\w+(?!\S)` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

[\w]*.[\w]{3}
I believe this works (according to regex101). I am new to this, but it matches only the ones with extensions, and ignores dhdgs.
It will match multiple letters and numbers, then a dot, and three letter extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *capture pattern*.

```
\b(\S.*?)\.\w+(?=\s|$)
```