# Create (sane/safe) filename from any (unsafe) string

Tags: python, filenames

I want to create a sane/safe filename (i.e. somewhat readable, no "strange" characters, etc.) from some random Unicode string (which might contain just anything).

(It doesn't matter for me whether the function is Cocoa, ObjC, Python, etc.)

---

Of course, there might be infinite many characters which might be strange. Thus, it is not really a solution to have a blacklist and to add more and more to that list over the time.

I could have a whitelist. However, I don't really know how to define it. `[a-zA-Z0-9 .]` is a start but I also want to accept unicode chars which can be displayed in a normal way.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you want this to be internationalizable?

Comment: @mydogisbox: No, just a single (unicode) filename from the input.

Comment: “no "strange" characters… but I also want to accept unicode chars which can be displayed in a normal way.” The problem that there's an intersection between those sets. For example, if a user writes an article about [Феликс Дзержинский](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feliks_Dzerzhinsky), is that ‘р’ a Latin ‘p’ or a Cyrillic ‘p’? (Yes, they really are two different characters. Paste into UnicodeChecker to see.)

Comment: … As for why that's a “strange” character, a few years ago, there was a flurry of news and analysis reports about how phishing scammers had started using characters like that to make fake but real-looking domain names (“paypal.com”, for a made-up-just-now example). Browsers such as Safari now render such domains as “Punycode” (bit like half-base64 half-ASCII) for that reason. So, that character and the many others like it can be used for good **or** evil—and that's the problem.

Comment: Since this isn't a one-to-one character mapping, it sounds like you'll also need to check for duplicate filenames.

Comment: -1. I don't think this question is well defined at all. "Sane" and "strange" mean nothing. Either accept anything that the filesystem actually accepts (in which case this question is a duplicate), or accept a clearly defined subset of ascii (in which case this question is trivial).

Comment: @Clément: Ofc it's not well defined. The question was also in the sense if there maybe is some straight-forward answer, so your comment is kind of the answer "no, there is not" - but I don't know that. Maybe Unicode defines something like invisible (strange) chars, or canonical chars or so. I don't know. Anyway, the accepted answer is kind of straight-forward and I'm happy with it now. And it's neither the two cases you describe, it's much better.

Comment: Questions should ask for code in one specific language, unless they are language-agnostic questions about algorithms, or unless they are specifically about interoperating between code written in two different languages (e.g. creating a Python extension in C or embedding a Python interpreter within a C program). Since everyone gave Python answers, I removed the other tags. I also agree that this is a duplicate, and marked it as such.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I specifically asked a language-agnostic question about an algorithm here. Python is just a good language to specify a generic algorithm but in my question I very specifically did not want it to be Python specific.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Python:

```
"".join(c for c in filename if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit() or c==' ').rstrip()
```

this accepts Unicode characters but removes line breaks, etc.

example:

```
filename = u"ad\nbla'{-+\)(ç?"
```

gives: `adblaç`

**edit**
*str.isalnum() does alphanumeric on one step. – comment from queueoverflow below. danodonovan hinted on keeping a dot included.*

```
keepcharacters = (' ','.','_')
"".join(c for c in filename if c.isalnum() or c in keepcharacters).rstrip()
```

Comment: Oh cool, yea, I didn't knew `str.isalpha()` also works for such unicode chars.

Comment: Doesn't this also omit spaces?

Comment: It does actually... Is that a problem here for @Albert? Otherwise just add `or x==' '`. The overhead is small because it will be the last thing to look for.

Comment: @Peter: Yea, but from this answer, it was easy enough to make my own function exactly fitting my needs. `c.isalpha()` is close enough to what I searched for. Of course, it's still not perfect (and you gave a good example in your comment on the question about different "p"s).

Comment: This isn't safe on Windows. First off, you need to protect against legacy device filenames like CON and NUL. Second, what about case sensitivity? You might overwrite another file on accident. Third, filenames with spaces at the end aren't handled correctly by Python on Windows. That's at least three ways to break it off the top of my head.

Comment: for your 3rd remark, I added `rstrip()`. As for CON and NUL etc., perhaps the desired file can be checked to end only with one out of a fixed list of allowed file extensions? As for case sensitivity and file-overwrite: the filename is a valid name at least, next step should be checking if the file not already exists before you overwrite (e.g. use `os.path.exists()`)

Comment: There even is `str.isalnum()` which does alphanumeric on one step.

Comment: To *not* strip out the period (full stop) `.` try ` "".join(c for c in filename if c.isalnum() or c in [' ', '.']).rstrip()`

Comment: Unicode characters can cause problems on some older filesystems - it's probably best to use unidecode or similar to convert characters to safe ASCII characters. Also, it [might be a good idea to remove spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2306003/210945).

Comment: A tiny subset of the potentially **dangerous** file names this would pass through:  a 5 gigabyte-long file name, `.......`, `nul`, `dir.exe`, the empty string.

Answer (score 15):

My requirements were conservative ( the generated filenames needed to be valid on multiple operating systems, including some ancient mobile OSs ). I ended up with:

```
    "".join([c for c in text if re.match(r'\w', c)])
```

That white lists the alphanumeric characters ( a-z, A-Z, 0-9 ) and the underscore. The regular expression can be compiled and cached for efficiency, if there are a lot of strings to be matched. For my case, it wouldn't have made any significant difference.

Comment: Using a regex to identify a single character from a set ...

Answer (score 13):

More or less what has been mentioned here with regexp, but in reverse (replace any NOT listed):

```
>>> import re
>>> filename = u"ad\nbla'{-+\)(ç1?"
>>> re.sub(r'[^\w\d-]','_',filename)
u'ad_bla__-_____1_'
```

Comment: Just use `\W` which "Matches anything other than a letter, digit or underscore. Equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`".

Answer (score 12):

I don't recommend using any of the other answers. They're bloated, use bad techniques, and replace tons of legal characters (some even removed all Unicode characters, which is nuts since they're legal in filenames). A few of them even import huge libraries just for this tiny, easy job... that's crazy.

**Here's a regex one-liner which efficiently replaces every illegal filesystem character and *nothing else.* No libraries, no bloat, just a perfectly legal filename in one simple command.**

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words

**Regex:**

```py
clean = re.sub(r"[/\\?%*:|\"<>\x7F\x00-\x1F]", "-", dirty)
```

**Usage:**

```
import re

# Here's a dirty, illegal filename full of control-characters and illegal chars.
dirty = "".join(["\\[/\\?%*:|\"<>0x7F0x00-0x1F]", chr(0x1F) * 15])

# Clean it in one fell swoop.
clean = re.sub(r"[/\\?%*:|\"<>\x7F\x00-\x1F]", "-", dirty)

# Result: "-[----------0x7F0x00-0x1F]---------------"
print(clean)
```

This was an extreme example where almost every character is illegal, because we constructed the dirty string with the same list of characters that the regex removes, and we even padded with a bunch of "0x1F (ascii 31)" at the end just to show that it also removes illegal control-characters.

This is it. This regex is the only answer you need. It handles every illegal character on modern filesystems (Mac, Windows and Linux). Removing *anything* more beyond this would fall under the category of "beautifying" and has **nothing** to do with making legal disk filenames.

---

**More work for Windows users:**

After you've run this command, you could optionally *also* check **the result** against the list of "special device names" on Windows (a case-insensitive list of words such as "CON", "AUX", "COM0", etc).

The illegal words can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations in the "Reserved words"  and "Comments" columns for the **NTFS** and **FAT** filesystems.

Filtering reserved words is only necessary if you plan to store the file on a NTFS or FAT-style disk. Because Windows reserves certain "magic filenames" for internal usage. It reserves them case-insensitively and without caring about the extension, meaning that for example `aux.c` is [an illegal filename on Windows](https://github.com/skeggsb/nouveau/issues/4) (very silly).

All Mac/Linux filesystems don't have silly limitations like that, so you don't have to do anything else if you're on a **good** filesystem. Heck, in fact, most of the "illegal characters" we filtered out in the regex are Windows-specific limitations. Mac/Linux filesystems can store most of them. But we filter them anyway since it makes the filenames portable to Windows machines.

Comment: Not sure if this is the point of the question, but this would be perfect if it also filtered out things like double spaces or ending names in periods. Just a note to anyone, more checks are needed!

Comment: This is a good answer, an essential piece of the puzzle.  I found another answer that is an invertible function.  Together they solved my problem :)

Comment: *trust* the regex

Answer (score 8):

There are a few reasonable answers here, but in my case I want to take something which is a string which might have spaces and punctuation and rather than just removing those, i would rather replace it with an underscore.  Even though spaces are an allowable filename character in most OS's they are problematic.  Also, in my case if the original string contained a period I didn't want that to pass through into the filename, or it would generate "extra extensions" that I might not want (I'm appending the extension myself)

```
def make_safe_filename(s):
    def safe_char(c):
        if c.isalnum():
            return c
        else:
            return "_"
    return "".join(safe_char(c) for c in s).rstrip("_")

print(make_safe_filename( "hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : die!!!" ) + ".gif")
```

prints:

> hello_you_crazy_______2579_people______die___.gif

Comment: I think that function might be better if repeated underscores were replaced with a single underscore. `re.sub('_{2,}', '_', 'hello_you_crazy_______2579_people______die___.gif')` `` `>> 'hello_you_crazy_2579_people_die_.gif'`

Comment: @Xevion But that increases the chance even more that different strings are mapped to the same filename.

Answer (score 7):

No solutions here, only problems that you must consider:

- what is your minimum maximum filename length? (e.g. DOS supporting only 8-11 characters; most OS don't support >256 characters)
- what filenames are forbidden in some context? (Windows still doesn't support saving a file as `CON.TXT` -- see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031022-00/?p=42073)
- remember that `.` and `..` have specific meanings (current/parent directory) and are therefore unsafe.
- is there a risk that filenames will collide -- either due to removal of characters or the same filename being used multiple times?

Consider just hashing the data and using the hexdump of that as a filename?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind to import other packages, then werkzeug has a method for sanitizing strings:

```py
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

secure_filename("hello.exe")
'hello.exe'
secure_filename("/../../.ssh")
'ssh'
secure_filename("DROP TABLE")
'DROP_TABLE'

#fork bomb on Linux
secure_filename(": () {: |: &} ;:")
''

#delete all system files on Windows
secure_filename("del*.*")
'del'
```

https://pypi.org/project/Werkzeug/

Comment: The tool is an entire WSGI application, the relevant code can be found here: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/a3b4572a34269efaca4d91fa4cd07dd7f6f94b6d/src/werkzeug/utils.py#L174-L218 *(Note: Never randomly trust code from the internet when it comes to security, please validate the code before using)*!!

Comment: I entirely agree and endorse. Do as @Torxed said and get the code rather than the entire library, and never trust security advice from strangers :P

Comment: **That is a horrible library if you need to support unicode/UTF.** It strips all unicode characters from the filenames. Besides, who the heck needs a library for something that a regex can do in one line? See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199182/8874388

Comment: Regex is hard to read, and with a library you get at least some level of community-proven testing. I would not want unicode in a filename. Chinese signs and Rocket-emoji makes poor file names.

Comment: @Anders_K If you prefer removing Unicode characters, that's on you and falls into the category of "beautification". Chinese letters, Scandiavian åäö, etc, are legal in filesystems. The list of ACTUALLY-illegal characters is well documented on Wikipedia (linked in my answer). Regex is easy to read, and this is a very simple regex which just removes the illegal characters and the range of ASCII 0-31 which are illegal control characters as mentioned on wikipedia. I just point this out because the regex is very, very simple, and sanitization doesn't need any library. Extra cleanup is OPTIONAL. ;)

Comment: @MitchMcMabers I must have misunderstood OP. I thought he/she needed to create safe strings from potentially malicious users.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with many other answers is that they only deal with character substitutions; not other issues.

Here is a comprehensive universal solution. It handles all types of issues for you, including (but not limited too) character substitution. It should cover all the bases.

Works in Windows, *nix, and almost every other file system.

```
def txt2filename(txt, chr_set='printable'):
    """Converts txt to a valid filename.

    Args:
        txt: The str to convert.
        chr_set:
            'printable':    Any printable character except those disallowed on Windows/*nix.
            'extended':     'printable' + extended ASCII character codes 128-255
            'universal':    For almost *any* file system. '-.0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    """

    FILLER = '-'
    MAX_LEN = 255  # Maximum length of filename is 255 bytes in Windows and some *nix flavors.

    # Step 1: Remove excluded characters.
    BLACK_LIST = set(chr(127) + r'<>:"/\|?*')                           # 127 is unprintable, the rest are illegal in Windows.
    white_lists = {
        'universal': {'-.0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'},
        'printable': {chr(x) for x in range(32, 127)} - BLACK_LIST,     # 0-32, 127 are unprintable,
        'extended' : {chr(x) for x in range(32, 256)} - BLACK_LIST,
    }
    white_list = white_lists[chr_set]
    result = ''.join(x
                     if x in white_list else FILLER
                     for x in txt)

    # Step 2: Device names, '.', and '..' are invalid filenames in Windows.
    DEVICE_NAMES = 'CON,PRN,AUX,NUL,COM1,COM2,COM3,COM4,' \
                   'COM5,COM6,COM7,COM8,COM9,LPT1,LPT2,' \
                   'LPT3,LPT4,LPT5,LPT6,LPT7,LPT8,LPT9,' \
                   'CONIN$,CONOUT$,..,.'.split(',')  # This list is an O(n) operation.
    if result in DEVICE_NAMES:
        result = f'{FILLER}{result}{FILLER}'

    # Step 3: Truncate long files while preserving the file extension.
    if len(result) > MAX_LEN:
        if '.' in txt:
            result, _, ext = result.rpartition('.')
            ext = '.' + ext
        else:
            ext = ''
        result = result[:MAX_LEN - len(ext)] + ext

    # Step 4: Windows does not allow filenames to end with '.' or ' ' or begin with ' '.
    result = re.sub(r'^[. ]', FILLER, result)
    result = re.sub(r' $', FILLER, result)

    return result
```

It replaces non-printable characters even if they are technically valid filenames because they are not always simple to deal with.

No external libraries needed.

Comment: I think the last two replacements contain a bug. You apparently wanted to write `result = re.sub(r"[. ]$", FILLER, result)`
`result = re.sub(r"^ ", FILLER, result)`. Or alternatively, just `result = re.sub(r"(^ |[. ]$)", FILLER, result)` would also work.

Comment: There is also a bug on the line `'CONIN$,CONOUT$,..,.'.split()`. It should be `'CONIN$,CONOUT$,..,.'.split(',')` instead. Note the added `','` argument. Else the `split()` operation does nothing.

Comment: @Roland Pihlakas: Nice catch. Fixed!

Answer (score 4):

I admit there are two schools of thought regarding DIY vs dependencies. But I come from the firm school of thought that prefers not to reinvent wheels, and to see canonical approaches to simple tasks like this. To wit, I am a fan of the pathvalidate library

https://pypi.org/project/pathvalidate/

Which includes a function `sanitize_filename()` which does what you're after.

I would preference this to any one of the numerous home baked solutions. In the ideal I'd like to see a sanitizer in os.path which is sensitive to filesystem differences and does not do unnecessary sanitising. I imagine pathvalidate takes the conservative approach and produces valid filenames that can span at least NTFS and ext4 comfortably, but it's hard to imagine it even bothers with old DOS constraints.

Comment: It's disingenuous to claim there's a school of "not inventing the wheel" that others may not subscribe to. By choosing to not re-invent the wheel *every single time*, which is what you seem to be implying, you don't get membership of a morally superior club, and your code is not necessarily better. It is of course a trade off, and depends on requirements and environment which is best in any case. For the problem that I came here for I'm certainly not going to import `pathvalidate`. I'm going to DIY a small fast appropriate solution. But thanks for identifying the library for those other times.

Comment: Is that a typo? I have no idea what you find disingenuous and if you read my answer as it states "I come from the firm school of thought that prefers not to reinvent wheels". It does not posit a 'school of "not inventing the wheel"' it refers to a "school of thought" which is a way of saying "a belief system" if you will, and only suggest what my personal belief is. That I believe reinventing the wheel is not a useful application of my time. Re-inventing, not inventing. Inventing new wheels is the hallmark of progress and to be encouraged.  Re-inventing old wheels is less interesting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Benrd, I still think I explained it adequately in my comment. If you have some alternative universe of measuring software that involves how interesting you find it - well, I haven't thought about that but presumably your comments may have validity in that universe, I won't comment there. I was assuming, perhaps rashly, that software should be evaluated against it's suitability for purpose and in that context it's always a trade off. I chose to "reinvent the wheel" on the occasion that brought me to this question because it was the most suitable solution this time.

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
for c in r'[]/\;,><&*:%=+@!#^()|?^':
    filename = filename.replace(c,'')
```

(just an example of characters you will want to remove)
The `r` in front of the string makes sure the string is interpreted in it's raw format, allowing you to remove backslash `\` as well

Edit:
regex solution in Python:

```
import re
re.sub(r'[]/\;,><&*:%=+@!#^()|?^', '', filename)
```

Comment: There might be infinite many characters which might be strange. It is not really a solution to add more and more to that list over the time.

Comment: I see; are the ALLOWED characters known?

Comment: I don't really know how to define the allowed chars. Basically I mean all chars which can be displayed and don't have some strange behavior (in that they have negative width or add a newline or so). That is what I mean with 'sane'. That is basically the whole question, because otherwise, it would be trivial.

Comment: I think you rather want "][[]" to capture both "[" and "]". I'm not sure though

Comment: @Albert: Unicode is not infinite, and as a user if I'm going to input a file name I don't really want strange program logic to decide what I may or may not put in there. Removing just enough to ensure safety (such as directory separators and relative path markers like `.` and `..`) is fine, but removing more? I'm not sure.

Comment: Quite sure this regex is wrong. [ is a special char in regex.

Comment: -1. The regex solution is clearly untested. As @CarsonIp points out, it uses regex-reserved characters, not only `[`, but also `]*+^?|`. Because of this, the regex fails to compile. Also, this approach just doesn't work well generally, because as the OP points out, a character blacklist simply doesn't scale well at all, so a whitelist is probably preferable.

Comment: +1. For my application, in a protected space, where failure will simply raise a message for correction and re-run, this is a fast and suitable approach. I'll do it without running a regex either. But I'll do it the other way around, rather than calling`replace` (function call each time) along the whole string for every check char: `filename = "".join(c in r"""[]/\;,><&*:%=+@!#^()'"|?^""" and "_" or c for c in filename)`. I've no idea if this is faster / "better", I just prefer it this way and it's one line instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

**Extra note for all other answers**

Add hash of original string to the end of filename. It will prevent conflicts
in case your conversion makes same filename from different strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came with, being inspired by uglycoyote:

```
import time

def make_safe_filename(s):
    def safe_char(c):
        if c.isalnum() or c=='.':
            return c
        else:
            return "_"

    safe = ""
    last_safe=False
    for c in s:
      if len(safe) > 200:
        return safe + "_" + str(time.time_ns() // 1000000)

      safe_c = safe_char(c)
      curr_safe = c != safe_c
      if not last_safe or not curr_safe:
        safe += safe_c
      last_safe=curr_safe
    return safe
```

And to test:

```
print(make_safe_filename( "hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!hello you crazy $#^#& 2579 people!!! : hi!!!" ) + ".gif")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to specify a replacement for any unwanted symbol. This way filename may look more readable.

```
>>> substitute_chars = {'/':'-', ' ':''}
>>> filename = 'Cedric_Kelly_12/10/2020 7:56 am_317168.pdf'
>>> "".join(substitute_chars.get(c, c) for c in filename)
'Cedric_Kelly_12-10-20207:56am_317168.pdf'
```