# Remove apostrophe from string in python

Tags: python, string, text

Good day, I need to remove apostrophes from a string that is being used to create a file. It causes an error because file names cant contain apostrophes. I read through other questions on stack overflow and some people are saying to use: string.replace("'", "")
I tried that but it doesn't remove the apostrophe.
Here is the code I'm running:

```
download_url = f'{result["link"]}'
song_name = f'{result["title"]}'
status = f'{result["status"]}'
correct_song_name = song_name.replace("'", "")
save_location = download_location()
urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url, save_location + 
correct_song_name + '.mp3')
```

Here is an example of what happens when it is fed a title with apostrophes: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/Test2/What is "this".mp3'

What am I doing wrong or what are the other ways of removing characters from the string?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406102/create-sane-safe-filename-from-any-unsafe-string) might be useful.

Comment: Please be aware that "apostrophe" would normally be understood to refer to single quotes, whereas the character that you are trying to remove is double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code only removes single quotes and not double quotes. The following would remove the correct character:

```
correct_song_name = song_name.replace('"', "")
```

If you have both single and double quotes, you can use:

```
correct_song_name = song_name.replace('"', "").replace("'", "")
```

Comment: I see now, it works thank you very much!

Comment: @JonathanLangford Great, glad it helped! You can mark the answer as the accepted one with the checkmark if it solved your issue :-)