# FileNotFoundError every time I try to download a video using PyTube

Tags: python, file-not-found, pytube

Every time I try to download a video using Pytube, it generates this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Recently it has been showing this error. Before, it worked completely fine. Here's my code:

```
def vid_only():
    for stream in yt.streams.filter(only_video=True, adaptive=True, file_extension="mp4"):
        res_avail.add((stream.resolution))
    r = ", ".join(res_avail)
    print(f"Available resolutions:  {r}")

    res_choose = input("Input your desired resolution: ")
    print("Downloading . . .")
    vid_download = yt.streams.filter(res=res_choose.lower()).first()
    vid_download.download(filename=yt.title + " VIDEO ONLY.mp4")

link = input("Input youtube link: ")
yt = YouTube(link)
res_avail = set()
stream_type = int(input("Types: \n1. Video only \n2. Audio only \n3. Video with audio \nEnter the number of the type you want to download: "))

if stream_type == 1:
    vid_only()
```

Is there something wrong with this line?

```
vid_download.download(filename=yt.title + " VIDEO ONLY.mp4")
```

Comment: Maybe it's the way you run the script, because it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, in my case the file contained illegal "filename" characters...  as the script above simply passes `yt.title` to the download call without making it "safe".

So I changed the `filename` line to...

```
filename = "".join([c for c in yt.title if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit() or c==' ']).rstrip()
```

... based on SO Answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7406369/1327508)