# How to create a directory with different language name in java?

Tags: java, windows, utf-8, cp1252

I am trying to create a directory with different language name in java, but the directory is not generated and appearing as "?????" in log.

```
{

        String strtobyte = "对不起拜托";
        byte[] b = strtobyte.getBytes(("Windows-1252"));
        String bytetostr = new String(b);
        tmpDir = new File(this.m_directory, bytetostr);
    }
```

Can someone please help me to create directory with different language names?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encoding of file names in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106161/encoding-of-file-names-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "UTF-8", instead of "Windows-1252".

Or, you can just do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    File f = new File("/Users/foldername", "对不起拜托");
    f.mkdir();
}
```

Comment: After i changed "Windows-1252" in to "UTF-8" also the folder is not getting generated but i could see this "å¯¹ä¸?èµ·æ‹œæ‰˜" in log.

Comment: @sureshkrishna The folder needs to exist first. If not, you need to create it, before creating the file.

Comment: I don't need file rather i want to create a folder/directory.