# how to check bad character present in the string in java

Tags: java

i have a string and i need a utility method which looks for bad character presence in the string and return some flag on that. Thanks for help in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "bad character" and [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184176/how-can-i-safely-encode-a-string-in-java-to-use-as-a-filename and especially the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1184180/814206 about *replacing* (instead of flagging) all 'bad' characters with other safe characters.

Comment: ï ¿ ½r    these characters i want to skip . i am not sure what others may so asked in a generic way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions to define what characters do you want to appear in a string. If something else appears, report it somehow.

Simple example:

```
String s = "humbapumpa jim";
if (!s.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) return false;
```

Or from the other side: define your "bad" characters and fire alert if they appear.

```
String s = "humbapumpa jim";
if (s.matches("[a]+")) return false;
```

More info on regular expressions in Java: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear exactly what you are trying to do from the question, but you can probably just use [String.indexOf(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) to detect the presence of the "bad character"

Comment: ï ¿ ½r these are something that cannot be input from keyboard so i thought might there must be some API which filters such characters